# Append value to Django model

Tags: python, django, database

I have 2 DB Models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    date_pub = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date Published")
```

and

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(to=Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My app was created recently, so i use `manage.py shell` to insert data to these models.

For example, let's say I created books with title `"Kolobok"` and `"Zolotaya Ribka"`. Next, I created customer `"Vasya"`. When I created customer `"Vasya"`, I pointed field `book` as "Kolobok". But over time, i want to append book `"Zolotaya Ribka"` to `"Vasya"` 's books.

How i can to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely need a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) instead. A many-to-many field means that a `Customer` can be linked to zero, one or more `Book`s (so here that would mean the customer bought zero, one or more books), and a `Book` can be linked to zero, one or more customers (so a book is bought by zero, one or more customers).

We thus can remodel this by introducing a field `books`:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

Then we can construct for example the books and the customer like you did:

```
b1 = Book.objects.create(title='Kolobok', author='')
b2 = Book.objects.create(title='Zolotaya Ribka', author='')
```

next we can create a customer:

```
c1 = Customer.objects.create(name='Vasya', surname='', age=73)
```

and then we can link the two books `b1` and `b2` to `c1`:

```
c1.books.add(b1, b2)
```

See the [documentation on *many-to-many relationships*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more information.